# Eclipse Android; Bitmap to large: OutOfMemory?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bitmap

My app is like a photo Album. In every activity is one picture and I can go from one activtiy to the next over a button. The pictures I use are 640x480 and not bigger than 150KB. But very often the app stops working because of an OutOfMemory-Error. Probably are the Bitmaps too large. What do I have to add into my code to add large Bitmaps efficently? Momentarily I even didn't define the Bitmaps in my Java-Code. They are only in XML-Code. I probably have to write s.th in my Java-Code. But what?

```
package com.example.xxx;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

public class PictureOne extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pictureone);}

public void Picture0 (View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, PageZero.class);             
        startActivity(i);}}

public void Picture2 (View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, PageTwo.class);             
        startActivity(i);}}
```

XML-Code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pic1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/left" 
        android:onClick="Picture0"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/right" 
        android:onClick="Picture2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 25-30 Bitmaps are used

Comment: "What do I have to add into my code" - depends on your code. Consider posting it.

Comment: well 640x480 bitmaps require 1.2 MB of memory to be hold in memory..

Comment: thats why I run out of Memory...@323go: I actually have no real code, because I only have a Picture defined in XML and then two Buttons to go further or go back. Not more is in my JavaCode

Comment: just follow this link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html from google's official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should use universal image loader by nostra and for viewing just images there is no point of stacking up activities.You can simply use view pager or image flipper.

Comment: ok, thx, I am very new in this. And These Image loader I have to add in my Java Code?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link..
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader.
yes  you have to add nostra image loader as a library to your android project.

Answer (score 0):

For loading large Bitmap's efficiently, just refer to this article:
[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

As you can see from there:

> To avoid java.lang.OutOfMemory exceptions, check the dimensions of a bitmap before decoding it, unless you absolutely trust the source to provide you with predictably sized image data that comfortably fits within the available memory.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) is the full section on Android Developers on displaying Bitmaps.

But also, you can try to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library which is very useful for this.